# How to glass an electron window when it's not focused?

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

Please give me a simple guide to glass an electron window when it's not in focused,

I have found an event for that from https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1985 (the code is bellow) but I don't know how to use it. and I can't find a way to glass the focusedWindow (from : https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#winfocus)

```
var app = require('app');

app.on('focused-window', function (focusedWindow) {
  doSomethingWithTheFocusedWindow(focusedWindow);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean glass a window? Do you mean fill it with content?

Comment: I wan't the window's opacity to be about .5 or transparent somehow

Comment: you could use [setOpacity](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetopacityopacity-windows-macos), although this only works on Windows and MacOS (not Linux). It could be set in the [blur and focus](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-blur) events for the window, to change opacity when it's in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at your question a little more carefully, it looks as if you might be having a little confusion between app, BrowserWindow, and some of the other components within electron. Here is a little more verbose example that hopefully ties all of the pieces together.

In a nutshell, the app is referred to as the [main process](https://electronjs.org/docs/glossary#main-process), which is not actually a Browser Window (also called a [renderer process](https://electronjs.org/docs/glossary#renderer-process)) itself. You have to create any windows you want. If you need it, communication between the main process and renderer processes is handled through [Inter-Process Communication channels](https://electronjs.org/docs/glossary#ipc).

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
app.on('ready', () => {
  let child = new BrowserWindow({ parent: top, show: false });
  child.loadURL('https://github.com');
  child.on('focus', () => { child.setOpacity(1); });
  child.on('blur', () => { child.setOpacity(0.5); });
  child.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    child.show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This works for me on macOS:

```
app.on ('browser-window-blur', function (event, browserWindow)
{
    browserWindow.setOpacity (0.5);
});
//
app.on ('browser-window-focus', function (event, browserWindow)
{
    browserWindow.setOpacity (1.0);
});
```

It seems that the app events interface has somehow evolved since the proposal you've mentioned. The events are named [browser-window-focus](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-browser-window-focus) and [browser-window-blur](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-browser-window-blur) and the associated callback function makes use of two parameters: `event` and `browserWindow`.

Comment: Huh, I'd never seen the `app`-level focus/blur events before; that's really cool if you want to apply a callback to all the windows in your app!

Comment: Actually, I didn't know either... I just found out, tried it in one of my apps, and it worked! Electron is definitely awesome!